# report filename that is being checked

Tags: pylint

How to make **pylint** print filename (and maybe counter) of that it checks at the moment?

Documentation shows how to format messages if a problem is found, but not how to report progress. https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/output.html

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't possible. It's easy to add to pylint's code:

```
index 258bfdc3..30bac9f1 100644
--- a/pylint/lint.py
+++ b/pylint/lint.py
@@ -839,6 +839,8 @@ class PyLinter(config.OptionsManagerMixIn,
             if not self.should_analyze_file(modname, filepath, is_argument=is_arg):
                 continue

+            print(modname)
+
             self.set_current_module(modname, filepath)
             # get the module representation
             ast_node = self.get_ast(filepath, modname)
```

but I never got to making this a proper pull request with an option and all.

Comment: In my code it still didn't get to output. Maybe because `pylint` was executed as a library. So, I had to turn file reports option in `pylinrc` file and filter the report later.